# Angular 2 CLI commands not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-cli, text-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the necessary packages installed to run the following command:

```
ng generate component navigation
```

However, everytime I do it results in a "New file" operation in a text editor program unknown to me. It looks like this:

[image: Angular 2 CLI Text Editor]

After this I cannot figure out how to work this editor. The only option I know is to close the window to exit.

Ideally I would like `ng` commands to work without opening the editor. But if anyone can help identify this editor and give me some basic commands about how to operate it I would accept this as an answer!

If it helps, I am running WSL on the creators update.

Comment: Not sure, could be EMACS. Try to set your EDITOR environment variable to an editor you know.

Comment: Just ran `echo $EDITOR` and nothing came up. Should I set one?

Comment: I have no experience with WSL but it is worth a try.

Comment: You certainly appear to have another `ng` executable in your path, so that is taking over rather than calling the "angular cli" `ng`. You should do a `which ng` to see where this is actually installed. Google says [possibly this](https://gist.github.com/matchy2/8504631)

Comment: As probably another indicator, you "should" really be running [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) as opposed to any "system" installed node, which you likely are not doing. This "should" always prepend to your `PATH` so your `npm i -g @angular/cli` install should then always be "first" when resolving in the `PATH`. You can use a bash flavor with linux executables or there is also a [native windows install](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) available. Point is what you are running is presently not running the script for `@angular/cli`

Comment: Thanks all. @Henry I will define a default editor. @Neil Lunn `which ng` responds with: _/usr/bin/ng_ Which I assume is incorrect since it is not running the `@angular/cli` script? In regards to `nvm` I will look into this further as it it certainly looks useful. Although I have been apprehensive about installing more programs on WSL since it is technically still in beta. It took a while to get npm running. So I will create a backup first before installing it. I appreciate your help both of you.

Comment: No it's not the correct one. If it were correct then you would see `node_modules/.bin` somewhere in the path. So you are in fact calling a completely different executable. BTW. Using `@` with multiple people does not actually inform everyone of your comment. Only the first usage :(

Comment: Oh how sad :( Thanks for that. Okay well I have no idea how that happened! So I will need to change it then. Weirdly `ng serve` does work so something must be going on...

Answer (score 1):

try doing this command

```
which -a ng
```

for me this output

```
/usr/local/bin/ng
/usr/bin/ng
```

if you then do a

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/ng
```

for me this output:

```
/usr/local/bin/ng -> ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

which is ok, but:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/ng
```

for me output:

```
/usr/bin/ng
```

which is, well, not so good. so I just did:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/ng /usr/bin/ng2
```

Now when I call ng it's the correct one.

(I got no idea what the other ng was actually for, or why my setup worked before I upgraded angular cli)